# Working between Popup and Background Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to set a variable in  popup window, labeled `i` and then send it to the background page. I believe that I can put the variable in as the "request", but I might be wrong about that. When I try to run the extension I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'sendRequest' of undefined

What am I missing?

Here is my popup.html file:

```
var i = 0;
function start(){
    alert("working");
    chrome.tabs.sendRequest(i);
}

function add(){
    i++;
    document.getElementById('box').value=i;
}

function sub(){
    i--;
    document.getElementById('box').value=i;
}
```

Comment: See if [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865850/google-chrome-extension-develompent) help you solve your case as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should call [chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-getBackgroundPage) function to get a reference to the window object of the background page. Here is an example where setIValue function is defined in the background page.

```
var i = 0, bgPage = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
function start(){
    alert("working");
    bgPage.setIValue(i);        
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, now if you can, I have one more questions. For .setIValue(i); how do I specify what value in bgPage I want to alter?

Comment: Do you mean "what variable" (instead of what value)? If you want to set a variable defined in the background page, just write `bgPage.myVariable = i`

Comment: Are there any permissions that I need to add? because I am getting an "Cannot call method 'getBackgroundPage' of undefined" and later "Cannot set property 'ctr' of undefined" when I try bgPage.ctr = i;

Comment: Do you load your extension as described [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html#load) (4-Load the extension) ?