# Message isn't passed between background.html and popup.html

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to pass data that is saved in sessionStorage from background.html to popup.html

background.html:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  data = sessionStorage.getItem(request.tabId);
  alert(data);
  sendResponse({ data: data });
});
```

and in popup.html:

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
  chrome.extension.sendRequest({ tabId: tab.id }, function(response) { 
    alert(response.data);
  });
});
```

The popup is opened by a pageAction button, when I click the button I get an alert box with "null" on the popup and then an alert box with the data that I stored in sessionStorage on the background!

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Have you considered using `localStorage`? Then you can access the data directly in the popup without passing messages.

Comment: I want the data to perish as soon as the session is over, isn't localStorage lasting?

Comment: `localStorage` is persistant. You could clear it when the the background page opens the next time though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've done something dumb.

I inspected the background page by opening `chrome-extension://[extension-id]/background.html` in a tab instead of clicking on "inspect active views: `background.html`" in the extensions management page. This caused the tab to catch the request and call `sendResponse`, but the popup expected the REAL background page to call `sendResponse` (and if I understand Google's documentation regarding message passing, the fact that sendResponse was called twice is root of the problem, because the first call clears the `request` object)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use message/request APIs. I think [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641626/working-between-popup-and-background-chrome-extension/8645077#8645077) may help you.

You also don't need sessionStorage, just store your data in a global variable of the background page. It will persist until the browser is closed or until the extension is restarted.

So, here is how I would rewrite your code:

background.html:

```
var data = {}; // Object storing data indexed by tab id
```

and in popup.html:

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
  alert(chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().data[tab.id]);
});
```

Note that `chrome.tabs.getSelected` is deprecated [since Chrome 16](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/whats_new.html#16), so popup code should be:

```
chrome.windows.getCurrent(function(win) { 
  chrome.tabs.query({'windowId': win.id, 'active': true}, function(tabArray) {
    alert(chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().data[tabArray[0].id]);
  }); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, see my own answer to the cause of the problem I was having - I tried using a global object as well as `sessionStorage` and `localStorage` to no avail. I still prefer `sessionStorage` to a global object because I'm storing a few MBs of data and it just seems "right", although I'm open opposing opinions :) Double thanks for telling me about the deprecation of `getSelected()`!

Comment: You're welcome. BTW, isn't the `sessionStorage` object the same one for background page and popup page (since they share the same "domain") ?

Comment: FYI, localStorage (and I guess sessionStorage) is not really designed to store large objects. Actually, it's quite [counter-productive](http://jsperf.com/localstorage-vs-cached-object) if you look at perfs.

Comment: I thought `sessionStorage` would behave the same as `localStorage` but it didn't work for me. This test case has convinced me to go with a simple object instead :)